# plot modulus functions in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

im pretty new to matplotlib and plottings.
im trying to plot the function |x| + |y| = 0.1 in matplotlib. but im unable to do due to the below syntax. Is there a way i can do this with single function ? Also if the range of x and y values are increased beyond [-0.1,0.11] graph is not correct. Kindly help
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are plotting a function of two variables, hence you can use `plt.contour`. If you rewrite your equation as `|x| + |y| - 0.1`, the "equal to zero" correspond to the contour level 0.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

l = 0.25 # plot the function for x, y in [-0.25, 0.25]
n = 500j # number of discretization points
x, y = np.mgrid[-l:l:n, -l:l:n]

# create a colormap with a single color
cmap = ListedColormap(["tab:blue", "tab:blue"])
plt.figure()
plt.contour(x, y, abs(x) + abs(y) - 0.1, levels=[0], cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```